# Несмотря на установку новой версии PIP терминал дает прежнюю, что мешает добавить новый модуль

Tags: python, pip, pil

У меня две взаимосвязанные задачи, одна из которых тянет другую:

1. требуется установить модуль `PIL`, но вижу ошибку, из которой следует, что версии `pip 22.0.4` недостаточно и требуется `pip 23.0.1`.
2. ставлю версию `pip 23.0.1`, и она успешно устанавливается. Однако команда `pip -V` дает прежнюю версию: `pip 22.0.4`

При этом команда `where python` дает имеющиеся установленные питоны, и на каждом из них, как следует из предупреждения терминала, версия `pip 23.0.1` уже стоит.

У меня Windows 10, версия Python 3.7

Comment: "но вижу ошибку, из которой следует, что версии pip 22.0.4 недостаточно и требуется pip 23.0.1." - приведите точный текст ошибки. Обычно выдает предупреждение (не ошибку), что есть более новая версия pip, и можно обновиться.

Comment: Как вы его обновляете?

Comment: @insolor, да, там предупреждение - ошибка рядом стоит: **ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PIL (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for PIL
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 23.0.1 is available.**

Comment: @wchistow, через команду `-m pip install --upgrade pip`

Comment: Коротко: модуль называется PIL, но устанавливать нужно пакет Pillow (по историческим причинам: насколько я помню, изначальный разработчик проект забросил, а новые разработчики поменяли название пакета, но не меняли название импортируемого модуля). pip в данном случае обновлять не обязательно.

Answer (score -4):

Попробуйте исполнить данный скрипт :

```
import os
import tkinter as tk
 
root= tk.Tk()
 
canvas1 = tk.Canvas(root, width = 300, height = 350, bg = 'lightsteelblue2', relief = 'raised')
canvas1.pack()
 
label1 = tk.Label(root, text='Upgrade PIP', bg = 'lightsteelblue2')
label1.config(font=('helvetica', 20))
canvas1.create_window(150, 80, window=label1)
 
def upgradePIP ():
    os.system('start cmd /k python.exe -m pip install --upgrade pip') 
    
button1 = tk.Button(text='      Upgrade PIP     ', command=upgradePIP, bg='green', fg='white', font=('helvetica', 12, 'bold'))
canvas1.create_window(150, 180, window=button1)
 
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]

Comment: Оборачивание команды обновления PIP в графический интерфейс никак не решает проблему, озвученную в вопросе.